# This seems like a bug in studio or compilator

Tags: c#

Problem is that after **Randomize** func, array **forcombo** equals **random_for_combo**, but I **do not** equate them anywhere. Please help.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sub = "1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9#10";
        string[] split = sub.Split('#');
        string[] forcombo = new string[split.Length / 2];
        int s = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= split.Length - 1; j += 2)
        {
            forcombo[s] = split[j];
            s++;
        }
        string[] random_for_combo = new string[forcombo.Length];
        random_for_combo = forcombo;
        MessageBox.Show(forcombo[0] + forcombo[1] + forcombo[2] + forcombo[3] + forcombo[4], "Before random");
        random_for_combo = RandomizeStrings(random_for_combo);
        MessageBox.Show(forcombo[0]+forcombo[1]+forcombo[2]+forcombo[3]+forcombo[4], "After random");
    }
    public static string[] RandomizeStrings(string[] arr)
    {

        ArrayList l1 = new ArrayList(arr.Length);
        ArrayList l2 = new ArrayList(arr.Length);
        foreach (object k in arr)
        {
            l1.Add(k.ToString());
        }
        while (l1.Count > 0)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int rand = rnd.Next(l1.Count);
            l2.Add(l1[rand]);
            l1.RemoveAt(rand);
            Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(50));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < l2.Count; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = l2[i].ToString();
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Some helpless info to complete question..

Comment: Best title ever. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: `random_for_combo = forcombo;` you're "equating" them there and you are basically showing the same message twice before and after randomization. I wont ask if this was written by you, my question is, have you actually read the code before posting this question.

Comment: It seems that you are randomizing, returning new array, but then in message box displaying data from old, un-randomized array. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Looks like a bug in **your code**. Don't blame Visual Studio for this, please.

Comment: This "bug in compiler" was easily discovered to be your own error if you had used the debugger and took a good look at the code. You are showing the same string before and after.

Comment: I randomized 'random_for_combo', NOT 'forcombo' and not written 'forcombo = random_for_combo', but it equals!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with this code:

1. You're copying the reference from one array variable into another:

   ```
   random_for_combo = forcombo;
   ```

   This does not make the two variables contain two arrays that contain the same values, the two values now refer to the same one array in memory. Change one, and it will appear the other one changed as well. Think of the two variables as postit notes with the address of a house on them, the same address. If you go to the house and rearrange the furniture, "both houses" will appear to be changed. There is only one house however.
2. When you pass the array to the randomize method, you're passing a *reference* to the array, not a *copy* of the array, which means that if you change the contents of the array, you're not working on a copy, you're working on the original. This means that the array you get passed, and the array you return, is the same one array in memory
3. Probably not the source of the bugs in your question, but you shouldn't construct new Random objects every time you use it in a loop, instead construct it once and reuse, otherwise you risk getting back just a few distinct values.

Lastly, if your gut reaction is "this is a bug in visual studio or C#", then it almost never is, always work on the presumption that it is your own code that is faulty. By "almost never" I would say that the chance of you hitting a bug in C# or Visual Studio by chance is none.

To make a new array with the same contents of another, you have a few options:

1. Explicitly make an array and copy over the elements one by one:

   ```
   random_for_combo = new string[forcombo.Length];
   for (int i = 0; i < forcombo.Length; i++)
       random_for_combo[i] = forcombo[i];
   ```
2. Use [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx) instead of the for-loop:

   ```
   random_for_combo = new string[forcombo.Length];
   Array.Copy(forcombo, random_for_combo, forcombo.Length);
   ```
3. Use the new Linq [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) extension method:

   ```
   random_for_combo = forcombo.ToArray();
   ```

   Note that even though this looks like a no-op (since forcombo is an array), you'll actually get a new array with the same contents.

Comment: I did not know that, sorry. I solved it by 
for (int i = 0; i <forcombo.Length; i++)
            {
                random_for_combo[i] = forcombo[i];
            }

Answer (score 0):

but you did here :

```
random_for_combo = forcombo;
```

you set random_for_combo so it point to forcombo.

if you want to use the original array than you need to copy it to new array
something like this (instead of the above line)

```
        string[] random_for_combo = new string[forcombo.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < forcombo.Length; i++)
        {
            random_for_combo[i] = forcombo[i];
        }
```